# SQL sum up records with similar id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table and I require to sum the payments and balance of the same id.

```
ID   BALANCE  PAYMENT  DATE
1    157      3        1/3/2021
1    157      4        3/3/2021
1    157      7        4/3/2021
1    157      8        9/3/2021
2    304      9        21/2/2021
3    208      3        18/5/2021
```

I need to get to this

```
ID   BALANCE  PAYMENT TOTAL
1    157      3       179 *(157+3+4+7+8)* 
1    157      4       179
1    157      7       179
1    157      8       179
2    304      9       313
3    208      3       211
```

And remove duplicates and eventually hide the payment column with a nested query to reduce confusion

```
ID   BALANCE  PAYMENT TOTAL
1    157      3       179
2    304      9       313
3    208      3       211
```

I tried using the 'select id, balance + payment from table' however that does not take in the id, and group by does not seem to work as well.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Mysql is not the same thing as SQL server please correct your tags

Comment: In your sample data the `BALANCE` values in all 4 rows for `ID=1` are the same. But none guarantees this (maybe except client-side logic - but this is not true guarantee, it is hope only). What output must be produced if these exists different `BALANCE` values for the same `ID` value?

Comment: In the intended output, there is an additional column `PAYMENT`. Does it make sense as the depicted value is only one record of the payment group but the output is mainly focused on aggregations? If it's deemed reasonable, then which record should be used ? The first value or any_value in the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the tricky bit is getting 1 balance

```
SELECT ID, MAX(BALANCE) BALANCE,MAX(BALANCE) + SUM(PAYMENT) TOTAL
FROM T
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: In the OP's intended output, there is an additional column `PAYMENT`. But I doubt its rationality though.

Comment: 'AND eventually hide the payment column;' - @blabla_bingo

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you P.Salmon for clearing up my doubts .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,balance,payment,sum(payment)+balance as TOTAL FROM TABLE_NAME group by id;
```

I tried a similar query here: https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/

```
SELECT customer_id,first_name,age,sum(age)+customer_id as total FROM Customers group by first_name;
```

Maybe you'll need to specify all columns in group by but this is a concept that you can use for this scenario.